# Creating trigger to update value of second column on update of first column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have structure like this for my table:

```
products:
mrp | discount | price
```

I want to create a trigger so that if I change the value of discount it sets the price accordingly.

```
create trigger updateprice on products 
after update 
as if(update(discount)) 
update products set price=((100-discount)/100)*mrp;
```

However this is giving me syntax error & I'm not able to find the exact code for it. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `BEFORE` trigger but not `AFTER`.

```
delimiter //

create trigger updateprice  before update on products 
  for each row begin
    if new.discount <> old.discount then
       set new.price = ( ( 100 - new.discount ) / 100 ) * new.mrp;
    end if;
  end;
//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: I don't understand, only after updating the discount column, I want price column to be updated, so logically it should be After and not Before. And I need to add if condition as well, I want to trigger an event on specific column.

Comment: You can't have handle to `NEW` data after the `AFTER` trigger fired. And as it is a math expression on the other column, you can calculate and set it in before trigger, using a condition too.

Comment: Condition can be like `if NEW.discount <> OLD.discount then set NEW.price = ...`.

Comment: It's giving me an error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax'

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46958/discussion-between-ravinder-and-shanil-soni)